# iOS - Swift: Parse signup - new user is saved even though text validation should prevent it

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func signUp(sender: AnyObject) {
    var user = PFUser()
    user.username = self.userNameTextField.text
    user.password = self.passWordTextField.text
    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil  && (user.username != nil && user.password != nil) {
            println("Sign Up successfull")                 

            //Go to main menu
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("go-to-main-menu", sender: nil)
        } else {
            let errorString = error.localizedDescription
            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "Invalid Signup"
            alert.message = "Sorry, a username (unique) and a password are required to create a new account."
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            alert.show()
            println(errorString)
        }
    }
}
```

So my goal is to prevent signup if 
(a) usnername is taken
(b) username **or** password are not filled in

Results:
1. Trying to sign up with both fields blank results in the alert
2. Trying to sign up with password blank results **no** alert and the user is saved
3. Trying to sign up with username blank  results in the alert

Why is result #2 happening since I am checking for `nil` in the *if statement*?

Now, if I change the validation to check for to check for *zero* length strings:

```
if error == nil && (user.username != "" && user.password != "")
```

...it crashes with this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

...on this line:

```
let errorString = error.localizedDescription
```

I have looked at [how to add an extra attribute to Parse a Signup function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172858/how-to-add-extra-attribute-to-parse-signup-function), but that's adding extra which I do not want or need.
I've also looked at "[Parse SignUp Failure Adds User Regardless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779837/parse-signup-failure-adds-user-regardless)" but I'm already doing the text check.

Comment: use user.username.length != 0 instead of ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with the length of the strings by using `countElements` to check if the length os more than 0. Also I would removethe brackets around the `user.username` and `user.password` check:

```
if error == nil  && countElements(user.username) > 0 && countElements(user.password) > 0 {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also work with `variable.isEmpty`. So for example, `username.isEmpty`. If you put this in an if statement and the username text field is empty, the if statement will run.

```
if (username.isEmpty) {

//...

}
```

Also, are you developing this app for iOS8? If so, you should be using `UIAlertController`, not `UIAlertView`

Comment: Yeah, I should change that but we initially were supporting iOS 7.1 and only just a few days ago decided to drop support.